# Library with sub-libraries and include directories, how do I do it in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project structured in this way:

```
project
 |\_subdir
 |   | Some .cxx files
 |   | some .h files (included with #include "foo.h"
 |    \_subdir
 |       | Some .h files (included with #include <subdir/foo.h>)
  \_subdir2
     | some .cxx files
     | some .h files (included with #include "foo.h"
      \_subdir2
         | Some .h files (included with #include <subdir2/foo.h>)
```

I need to do a few things here:

1. The `subdir/subdir` directories should be publicly available for use in programs that use this library with `#include <subdir/foo.h>`.
2. The `subdir` directories should produce their own statically linked libraries so that I can run tests making sure that the dependency relationships between the different subdir directories are maintained.
3. The whole thing should produce either a shared or static library that has everything in all the `subdir` directories and can be linked to by programs using this library.

Currently I have a build system that I've made using autotools (but not automake) plus some custom made perl scripts that process the dependency output from the -M flags and create custom makefiles that express dependency information. Additionally, they create an include directory that's a linkfarm so everybody can use `#include <subdir/foo.h>` and just -I the linkfarm directory.

I want to convert this to CMake, but I'm at a loss as to how to handle the subdir structure and includes. I can re-arrange the directory structure somewhat if absolutely necessary, but I would very much like to preserve the pseudo-independence of the various subdir directories, partly because it's very important to me to be able to make sure the sub-libraries have a specific dependency relationship as a way to maintain modularity and cleanliness.

How would I do this in CMake? Do I have move the `subdir/subdir` directories?

Because it looks like if I add the `subdir` directories as a public include, then things will go really awry as people will see the private .h files at the `subdir` level as well as being able to include the .cxx files that are in them. Even worse, they will see them as top-level includes (i.e. `#include <bar.cxx>` where `bar.cxx` is a private implementation file who's object code should already be in a library).

But if add `subdir/subdir` as an include directory, the `.h` files won't appear in subdirectories like they should (i.e. `#include <subdir/public.h>` won't work, instead I'll have to use `#include <public.h>` which isn't my intent at all).

Comment: I'm still struggling with this. cmake doesn't like producing static and shared libraries from the same target. :-/ So this is becoming a lot more annoying and complicated that I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 2):

If you bother about **users** of your library, they will see **installed** files, not ones in the *source*/*build* directories. If you don't install private headers (from `subdir/`), a user won't see them.

But if you do not intend to install library, then you may **separate public and private** include trees. E.g. each project may have *private* headers directly in its source directory, and *public* headers under its `include/` subdirectory:

```
  project
 |\_subdir
 |   | Some .cxx files
 |   | Private .h files (included with #include "foo.h")
 |    \_include (public include directory)
 |       \_subdir
 |         | Public .h files (included with #include <subdir/foo.h>)
  \_subdir2
     | some .cxx files
     | Private .h files (included with #include "foo.h")
      \_include (public include directory)
         \_subdir2
           | Public .h files (included with #include <subdir2/foo.h>)
```

Comment: I do care about users. One goal is to build an rpm out of this, and so I will have to be able to install the public include directories. The private ones are only ever used internally to a given sub-library. The sub-libraries will not be part of the install. But the public include directories and the overarching library that is made of the sub-libraries will be.